# email alert not triggering

Tags: workflow, process-builder, email-alert, workflowrule

We have a unique situation now as we are transitioning to 2 separate SFDC instances and the business is not interested in SF to SF Connection. So at this point, once a deliverable is generated by the demand gen team in instance 1, I have to either add or update the contact in the corporate instance for the sales reps to follow up on. I need an email alert to go out to notify the rep and sales ops after I do this.

```
    AND(
ISPICKVAL(Sequence_Stage__c, "Deliverable"),
ISPICKVAL(Contact_Status1__c, "Teleprospecting Qualified"),
LastModifiedDate = NOW(),
LastModifiedById = 'MY SFDC USER ID'
)
```

This workflow criteria is not triggering the email. How can I modify so that it triggers? I have this workflow set to eval upon creation and any time it's edited to meet criteria. Should I use PB instead of workflow?

Comment: Can you try taking the "LastModifiedDate = NOW()," condition off? now() gives you the timestamp of that instance including seconds. If there is a delay of a sec in your process, it wouldn't fire.

Comment: Are you trying to trigger an email from instance 2 based on the changes to the record on instance 1? Also, have you checked the Debug Logs by navigating to Setup > Debug Logs and checked the reason for emails not being triggered? Is it that the criteria is not being fulfilled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend removing the `LastModifiedDate` and `LastModifiedById` conditions within your Workflow rule criteria. Also, the `LastModifiedById` should be compared with an ID field i.e. a Salesforce Id of the User record for the **MY SFDC USER ID** user, instead of comparing it with the name of the user.

Remove these from your rule criteria and the workflow should execute I believe. If it does not, please share the Debug Log snapshot to understand the issue better.

Comment: It was my actual ID, I just removed it for the post and added MY SFDC USER ID for this post. I am going to remove the last modified date and user and test that. I just don't want it to trigger unless I am the one adding the deliverable to instance 1. I will mark this as answered if the removal of those fields fixes it.